# How do you save an image with fabric.js with node.js at a specific dpi?

Tags: imagemagick, fabricjs

When I generate a 2000x2000 image using createCanvasForNode and save the image using createPNGStream, this creates a 2000x2000 72dpi file.  But If I need a 13.33"x13x33" **150dpi** file for a printer, should I double the multiplier, resulting in a 4000x4000 image, then use a tool like imagemagick to set it to 150dpi?  Wouldn't this cut it back down to 2000x2000? Is this the right approach?

Comment: If you want to print 13.33" at 150dpi, you need 2000pixels - that's all. The dpi should be irrelevant because any half-decent printing software should be able to accommodate your needs as long as you have enough pixels.

Comment: canvas produced pngs are normallu 96DPI. are you sure they are at 72dpi?